# Firebase web push notification Service worker issue

Tags: firebase, web, push-notification, push

I am new to web push notification area. I want to send firebase web notifications from web to web. I tried doing that and ended up with this error

FirebaseError: Messaging: We are unable to register the default service worker. Failed to register a ServiceWorker: A bad HTTP response code (404) was received when fetching the script. (messaging/failed-serviceworker-registration)

I dont know where am I went wrong. Thanks in Advance

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Finally got the answer.

We need to copy firebase-messaging-sw.js file and save it in the root of the folder. 
Since I used xampp, I ve push my push folder inside htdocs folder (/xampp/htdocs/push/), but you need to make sure that the firebase-messaging-sw.js should be in the root of the localhost(/xampp/htdocs/). i.e, when you search localhost/firebase-messaging-sw.js in browser, you shouldn't get a 404 error.

Comment: Whoever downvoted, it would be more useful to explain what you find objectionable. Just curious to know where I went wrong. Thanks

Comment: I gave you that answer already and you didn't mark it as correct.

Comment: It was not clear that the sw.js file should be there in the root folder no matter where your other files are served.But I upvoted your answer because I got the clue from your answer

Comment: Hi, I am also facing same issue. my firebase file is in ../messaging/firebase-messaging-sw.js but it is expecting .../firebase-messaging-sw.js. how can I bring my file to root directory ? can any one explain for me. I am very to new to PWA development .

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the service worker file `firebase-messaging-sw.js` to the location where your files are served. This is the service worker firebase looks for.

Also, you need to share code with examples of what you are doing. No one is going to write your code from scratch.